# It is not XML or JSON, what am I looking at here? Can I easily convert this into a table?

Tags: oracle, parsing

I've been asked to pull data out of an existing database for a working program.  The data relates to a filter utility.  I need to be able to pull out the filter data and eventually build an SQL statement to match.  The problem is, I do not recognize the data format.

```
<Filter Entity="Ticket">
    <Where>
        <Field Name="COLUMN_1" Value="A" CaseSensitive="false" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_2" Value="B" CaseSensitive="false" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_3" Value="C" CaseSensitive="false" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_4" Value="D" CaseSensitive="false" />
    </Where>
    <Sort>
        <Field Name="COLUMN_1" Direction="Ascending" />
    </Sort>
    <Grouping>
        <Field Name="COLUMN_1" Order="0" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_2" Order="1" />
    </Grouping>
</Filter>
```

In the end, I need to parse this into some sort of usable format.  To me, that means a table.  I have used the XMLTable function in Oracle in the past, which would work great if this were XML.  Anyone have some tips?

Desired output table:

```
|CLAUSE   |NAME     |VALUE |CASE  |DIRECTION |ORDER |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Where    |COLUMN_1 |A     |false |          |      |
|Where    |COLUMN_2 |B     |false |          |      |
|Where    |COLUMN_3 |C     |false |          |      |
|Where    |COLUMN_4 |D     |false |          |      |
|Sort     |COLUMN_1 |      |      |Ascending |      |
|Grouping |COLUMN_2 |      |      |          |0     |
|Grouping |COLUMN_1 |      |      |          |1     |
```

DB is Oracle 11g.  I do not know what language was used to build the application.

Comment: What makes you say it's not XML? I mean, it clearly shares features of xml, perhaps without some of the strict namespacing syntax, but as a snippet, it looks reasonably well formed. If your oracle parser needs it to be XML, then what's the minimum that you need to add (as a header/footer) to the file in order to make it pass that test?

Comment: In Oracle, I normally use the XMLTable function to parse XML into a table.  That function expects <filter><where><name>COLUMN_1</name><value>A</value></where></filter>.  When I pass the above string in, it does not recognize the values within the elements.

Comment: OK, I see - there's a famous philosophical split between "elemental" XML use, and "attribute" usage. The usage in your post is attribute-based, but here in the comments, looks like the common XMLTable function extracts element content. It's not exactly the same, but this oracle page might go some way towards an explanation: https://community.oracle.com/thread/552311?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is XML, as Tom Kimber said in comments; it's just using attributes more than you might have hoped rather than element/node values.

You can use XMLTable to extract attribute values as well as element/node values:

```
select * from xmltable (
  '/Filter/*/Field'
  passing xmltype('<Filter Entity="Ticket">
    <Where>
        <Field Name="COLUMN_1" Value="A" CaseSensitive="false" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_2" Value="B" CaseSensitive="false" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_3" Value="C" CaseSensitive="false" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_4" Value="D" CaseSensitive="false" />
    </Where>
    <Sort>
        <Field Name="COLUMN_1" Direction="Ascending" />
    </Sort>
    <Grouping>
        <Field Name="COLUMN_1" Order="0" />
        <Field Name="COLUMN_2" Order="1" />
    </Grouping>
</Filter>')
  columns clause varchar2(10) path 'local-name(..)',
    name varchar2(10) path '@Name',
    value varchar2(10) path '@Value',
    case_sensitive varchar2(5) path '@CaseSensitive',
    direction varchar2(10) path '@Direction',
    order_num number path '@Order'
);

CLAUSE     NAME       VALUE      CASE_ DIRECTION   ORDER_NUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ---------- ----------
Where      COLUMN_1   A          false                      
Where      COLUMN_2   B          false                      
Where      COLUMN_3   C          false                      
Where      COLUMN_4   D          false                      
Sort       COLUMN_1                    Ascending            
Grouping   COLUMN_1                                        0
Grouping   COLUMN_2                                        1
```

The `@attr` in the path gets an attribute with that name; the `local-name(..)` gets the element name of the parent (of the Field node).

You could also use a more complicated XPath to convert the attributes into element values, for instance, but I'm not sure you'd gain much here.